# Strange problem about android bootanimation child process affects memory occupation of its parent process init

Tags: android, linux, memory, process, init

This problem may be related to Android or Linux. If you are not familiar with Android, let me introduce init and bootanimation in brief first. Android init is the same as Linux init. It is the first process in user space. The pid is 1. Init process will do some system initializations defined in init.rc. One of the initialization is the boot animation. It is played by the process named bootanimation. Bootanimation is a native process. It plays the animation using OpenGL ES. Boot animation is usually described by a zip file with dozens or hundreds of static images. Play them in certain rate becomes animation.

Now the strange problem comes. It's about memory occupation of init process. In a clean android 8.1.0 system, the memory occupied by init exceeds 40M+. We can find out allocation detail by adb shell command 'dumpsys meminfo init'.

```
                   Pss
                 Total
                ------
  Native Heap     1076
  Dalvik Heap        0
        Stack       16
    Other dev      363
   Other mmap      333
   EGL mtrack    10040
    GL mtrack    29170
      Unknown       32
        TOTAL    41030
```

We can see that graphics related EGL/GL consumes most of the memory. Normally, init is a backend process. It has nothing to do with graphics. Then why graphics related memory takes the most. The only thing related to graphics I can figure out is boot animation. As described above, it is started/forked by init process. So I did some tests. If I disabled boot animation, memory occupation of init did decrease a lot to about 20M. I also did other tests. I tried to modify the source code of bootanimation to load and render a single image instead of hundreds of images. Memory occupation of init also decreased a lot. It means memory occupation of init has something to do with numbers of images loaded by bootanimation. I did further test and found that memory occupation of init will decrease a lot after forking bootanimation process by init. It seems that memory is transferred from init to its child process bootanimation.

Then comes my final question: as a child process, why will bootanimation affect the memory occupation of its parent process? When bootanimation process exits, shouldn't all resources occupied be release?

Extra comments: Although in my sense, when a process exits, all resources should be released. And the android source codes written by Google should be seasoned and have no bug. I still doubted about leak of resources in bootanimation. Bootanimation uses SkBitmap, which is in skia library, to load images and use OpenGL ES 1.0 textures to render them. I confirmed if I didn't confirm wrongly, that SkBitmap and OpenGL textures would be destroyed correctly. You guys may have interests in related android source codes.

Core code for playing animation in bootanimation:
http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/bootanimation/BootAnimation.cpp#862
Code for loading image:
http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/bootanimation/BootAnimation.cpp#190
Code for starting bootanimation in init:
http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/system/core/init/service.cpp#688

Thanks for all your answers, suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 0):

After a new series of tests and code reading, I found something new. I will add some new comments. This problem has nothing to do with init. The problem is related to implementation of *dumpsys meminfo*. Process memory displayed by *dumpsys meminfo* consists of two parts. One part is directly allocated by this process. Such as Dalvik Heap and Native Heap. While the other part is not directly allocated by this process, it is allocated by system just caused by this process. EGL/GL mtrack part shows above belong to this part. Tracking this part of memory is implemented by different hardware platform. Is is counted by display driver. What I am using is a MTK platform. It will track GL memory for those processes that do real GL operations. I believe these statistics is accurate. But there is total GL memory consumed by the system, that is the total GL mtrack value we can see when execute *dumpsys meminfo* without extra parameters. It may be not equal to the sum of counted GL values of all accounted processes. Then it accounts the difference of the total GL memory and sum of GL memory to init process. Because init is the ancestor process of all other processes. So the value to GL mtrack of init looks large, it is not allocated by init nor caused by init actually.

Now we can explain the very strange problem above and know it has nothing to do with process init. But my question still remain unresolved. That is, why event *bootanimation* is terminated, GL memory allocated by it is not freed? Does it mean leak of resource? Or maybe can I think it as a bug of mtk display driver?